# How to copy files from one ECS service to another?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

We know that ECS runs containers so is it possible to transfer files between two ECS services in the same cluster?
I am using **Fargate** as launch type for my ECS instances

Answer (score 2):

There are several approaches you use to solve this problem, however I would suggest utilising a shared NFS mount through the managed [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) service within both sets of containers.

AWS [added support for EFS within Fargate containers](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/04/amazon-ecs-aws-fargate-support-amazon-efs-filesystems-generally-available/) for exactly this problem.

By utilising this all containers that have it configured in their task will be able to access the EFS file system as if it's a local volume.

More information is available in the [Amazon EFS volumes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/efs-volumes.html) documentation.